# How to generate a candle stick chart with QuestDB?

Tags: sql, questdb

I have a table with market data. The table structure looks like this:

| symbol | side | price | amount | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTC-USD | buy | 35831.56 | 0.00051151 | 2023-11-15T10:42:11.754626Z |

I need to aggregate prices for a given symbol by time intervals. In each time interval, I need to know: the opening price, closing price, maximum price and minimum price.

Comment: What is the time interval you want?

Comment: Ideally, it should be configurable, but 1 hour would make a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open would be first price, close would be last price, Use [`sample`](https://questdb.io/blog/2022/11/23/sql-extensions-time-series-data-questdb-part-ii/#understanding-the-basics-of-sample-by).

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP,
    FIRST(PRICE) AS OPEN_PRICE,
    LAST(PRICE) AS CLOSE_PRICE,
    MAX(PRICE) AS MAX_PRICE,
    MIN(PRICE) AS MIN_PRICE,
FROM trades
SAMPLE BY 1h
```